# Compiler errors from simple Visual C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to make program run. When I try Hello World in win32 project/.cpp file I get bunch of errors

1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>hello.cpp
1>...\projects\helloworld3\helloworld3\hello.cpp(7) : error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
1>...\projects\helloworld3\helloworld3\hello.cpp(7) : error C2001: newline in constant
1>...\projects\helloworld3\helloworld3\hello.cpp(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'return'
1>Build log was saved at "file:/...\Projects\HelloWorld3\HelloWorld3\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>HelloWorld3 - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{


cout <<"Hello World!<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you get a chance, you should really edit your question to give it a better subject line. "Visual C++" could mean anything at all. That won't make people eager to read it.

Comment: But, RichieHindle, I was hoping to give him 15 minutes or so to maybe do it on his own...

Comment: @John: Sorry, you're quite right, I should have given ee1234 more of a chance to do it.

Answer (score 3):

cout is in the namespace "std", so you have two options:

1. prefix its use with std

   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
2. declare that you are using the
   namespace std

   using namespace std;

Comment: I did it, but now I get : error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier error

Comment: endl is also in the namespace std... I updated my answer to reflect that.  Try using #2 instead, put "using namespace std;" near the top of your file and you can avoid prefixing everything with "std::"

Comment: It worked. Thank You. Can someone recommend me video training or a book?

Answer (score 3):

> 1>...\projects\helloworld3\helloworld3\hello.cpp(7) : error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier

What this is saying is that it doesn't know what cout is. In C++ names can be in namespaces. In the case of cout it is in the namespace std. You can tell the compiler to look there in 2 ways:

- with the line, `using namespace std;` this tells the compiler to bring in all the names in the namespace std into the current one.
- by using the scope resolution operator `::`. as in `std::cout` Here you are telling the compiler exactly where to find the name.

> 1>...\projects\helloworld3\helloworld3\hello.cpp(7) : error C2001: newline in constant

This error says that the compiler is looking at a constant, in this case a string, and it found a newline where it didn't expect one. This is almost always a missing end quote.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `std::cout` and `std::endl` rather than `cout` and `endl`, or do this after the `#include`:

```
using namespace std;
```

The `using` clause makes your code more succinct, but in a large program it can be hard to keep track of where the names are coming from, so it can be better to be use the more verbose but more explicit `std::cout` / `std::endl`.

You're also missing a closing quote here:

```
cout <<"Hello World!<<endl;
```

You should have:

```
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

ee1234. Seeing as this was likely your very first C++ program, go have a look at [CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) it has a pretty straightforward and basic tutorial. That is exactly where I started when I first jumped into c++. As far as good books go, well just do a search on SO for 'C++ Books' and you should have a plethora of good posts talking about appropriate beginner->advanced books.

Answer (score 1):

Since cout is present within the standard namespace, you should either include

```
using namespace std;
```

at the start of your code, under your includes, or use std:: in front of every function call.
When placing an opening quote for a string, you should always include a closing quote aswell. This results in

```
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

Another way to write this would be:

```
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
```

The \n results in a new line feed.